# How to Pin to Bottom/Desktop UWP Application Using AHK Windows 10

Tags: windows, script, autohotkey, window

I'm aware of using `setParent` from DLL in Windows and I can pin Win32 application on Windows already with this script

```
#o::
  Current := WinExist("A")
  ;ParentID := WinExist("ahk_exe Explorer.EXE ahk_class Progman ")
  ;MsgBox, %ParentID%
  Parent := Parent ? 0 : DllCall("GetShellWindow") ; <-- toggle
  ;Parent := Parent ? 0 : ParentID ; <-- toggle
  ; the window will be dettached if 0 is passed as parent's hWnd
  DllCall("SetParent", UInt, Current, UInt, Parent )
Return
```

Source : https://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/61233-how-to-toggle-pin-to-desktop-always-on-bottom/

But the problem is, I want to pin to bottom for UWP Application, but it only blink when I press win+o, it seems UWP application is not having same trait with Win32 application

My goal is to make Microsoft To Do shown when I use <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd>, (or Win Peek), like MS Gadget (I use MS gadget in Windows 10, because I can't live without it), I tried `WinSet,Bottom`, no luck because it's the same as <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>esc</kbd> shortcutkey, only send window to bottom.

Is there anyway to pin UWP application always to to desktop or it's not possible?

Comment: Did you ever figure out a way to do this?

Comment: @Coldblackice sadly no, based on conversation with the developer, AHK can't access host.exe that handle the UWP app, so I gave up, and move on with my life. I use Windows gadget on windows 10